# NPM scripts not showing in the explorer sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

I have this problem with Visual Studio Code for Windows 10: I can't see the NPM scripts in the explorer sidebar.

I deleted all the extensions, uninstalled VS Code, and installed the latest version of VS Code again with no custom options and no extensions, but it didn't solve my problem; the NPM scripts menu does not appear.

How could I fix this so that the NPM Scripts menu option is shown again?

Comment: Did you try `View/Open View...` Type `NPM`  Click on `NPM Scripts`.

Comment: In the lastest version of vscode 1.55.0 user setup for Windows 10 x64, it does not appear.

Comment: In my case it was a "Settings Sync" issue that disabled the `vscode.npm` extension, see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146342.

Answer (score 76):

Few places to look for the NPM-Scripts explorer :

The npm-scripts explorer can be enabled or disabled with the below settings, in VSCode's [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

[`"npm.enableScriptExplorer": false`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_npm-script-running)
Default value is [`false`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=%22npm.enableScriptExplorer%22), change to `true` and it should work. Try restarting VSCode for changes to take effect(although a restart is not often required) if it doesn't show up.

Another very hard to notice place is the three dots `...` in the top right corner of your project explorer (verify if **NPM scripts** is checked). This is something which I had experienced personally for a different extension.

[image]

Comment: Tried all the places with the latest version of vscode (1.55.0), but NPM Scripts does not appear. I tried also to edit directly the file settings.json, but not solved. With the previous version of vscode (1.54.3) this problem does not appear.

Comment: I can understand how frustrating it becomes. Been there myself.

Comment: I would recommend you to try creating an issue on their github. I see people have faced [similar issues in past](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22npm+script+explorer%22) and complain about 1.55 too (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120279)

Comment: With the latest version of vscode 1.84.2 the "NPM Scripts" option is no longer in that menu. Adding the suggested flag to the settings has no effect.

Comment: @Organic Tested for 1.84.2. The `...` location is still valid in my case.

Answer (score 25):

### Version 1.59.1

Go to **View** -> **Open View** and type: `npm scripts`:

[image]

Comment: It's not on the list.

Comment: @Organic which version? this will only show on NPM projects, so ensure your folder has a `package.json` on it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I spent over 2 hours on this trying all the suggestions and nothing worked except after opening package.json. I'm guessing it was because I moved it to the bottom right of the UI. I guess it worked for most people because they probably didn't move the NPM Scripts panel to some other place other than the default location.

Answer (score 16):

1. Open "File > Preferences > Settings"
2. Search "npm script"
3. Toggle "Npm: Enable Script Explorer"
4. Close VSCode; reopen

[image]

Comment: Side-note: I had to restart my VSCode after enabling this option.

Comment: This option doesn't exist int he latest version of VSCode.

Comment: @Sebastian I tried all suggestions and nothing worked for me because I had the NPM Scripts at the bottom right side of the terminal. When the panel is in this location it's no longer visible or retrievable from any UI or settings. What made it come back was to open package.json, which somehow forced it to reload.

Answer (score 16):

Appreciate I may be a bit late to answer this question. For me, this was due to npm scripts not being selected to display in explorer. Once I had selected the box, the npm scripts window was available to view.

[image: Visual description for enabling npm scripts window in VS code]

Comment: Thank You, it just disappeared for me. :D

Comment: Same for me that's what I was missing, thanks so much!

Comment: This is culprit #1. Is it silly it's not on by default?

Comment: It's no longer in that menu.

Comment: @Kalnode [No it's not](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts/issues/74#:~:text=I%20didn%27t%20want%20to%20show%20it%20by%20default%20to%20not%20pollute%20the%20Explorer.)

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully, this has just been fixed - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120279#event-4631666095 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120279#issuecomment-824950294 seeking test verification.

---

It is in the Insiders now and in Stable early May, 2021.  It fixed it for me.

---

`View/Open View...`
Type `NPM`
Click on `NPM Scripts`

If it still isn't working, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119868

Is your `package.json` at the root level?  Does it make any difference if you open your `package.json` first, and then check for the view?  Or try opening another `.json` file (or even the Release Notes has been reported as working) and then do a `Reload`.  Otherwise, add your info to the issue.

Comment: Nope, NPM scripts is not on the list of views to open.

Answer (score 7):

It happens to me sometimes when I open VSCODE.
Whenever it happens I simply load a package.json file.
The NPM SCRIPTS menu still appears when I close the package.json file.

If that doesn't do the trick, try installing NPM-Scripts extension.

Comment: Oh.. how could I miss your answer, I'm sorry I added the same answer. I will up-vote yours

Comment: OMG I owe you my sanity. None of the other suggestions worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try to delete package-lock.json and restart VSCode.
In my case it worked.

Comment: No clue why that worked, but it did

Comment: Just a restart for me. Dumb vscode...

Answer (score 4):

Work around: If I leave an editor tab open with my package.json (I have one in the root, and in two other places), close and re-open VSC, then it seems to 'find' the NPM View.

---

TL;DR;
My VSC (1.55.2) is inconsistently showing / not showing the NPM View.

When it starts without the view, I cannot use View->Open "npm".
No option in Explorer options (...)

When it starts with the view, View->Open has a result for "npm".
Has option in Explorer options (...)

Bug report here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120279

Answer (score 1):

If it worked normally before but now it does not, and you have the extension installed and enabled. Then **all you have to do is open your package.json file and it will be available again.**

I guess this weird behavior happens when you disable all your extensions or may happen if you're installing/removing extensions from a remote container

Comment: This just happened to me.  I didn't disable extensions, but I did merge from a branch that caused a lot of errors in a folder that has lots of projects.  Even when I restarted VsCode NPM Scripts was nowhere to be found, and the other suggestions did not work.  Once I opened packaged.json NPM Scripts just popped up.

Answer (score 0):

For me It suddenly appeared after I hit Run, start debugging.

Answer (score -2):

You can install [NPM-Scripts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jianglinghao.vscode-npm-scripts) extension which does the same as npm scripts functionality which was build into vscode.

Comment: Good to know about this. But I think OP just wants to fix the original built int functionality, instead of replacing it with different extension.