# 'NPM Scripts' missing in VS Code after update to 1.58.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

The "NPM Scripts" view is missing from Views dropdown in the Explorer in my VS Code after I updated to version 1.58.0 today.

How do I enable that?

I have tried "Reload Window", restarting VSCode altogether and adding `"npm.enableScriptExplorer": true` to no avail.

P.S. my angular project is not in top-level directory, but it made no difference before this update.

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: I only can get the NPM Script view to show when I am in the folder that contains the package.json file.  I'm beginning to wonder if either this feature was changed (nothing in the release notes mentions it though), or its bugged (apparently its been [bugged before](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120279)).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66945789/6530134 for previous issues about this.

Comment: Thanks for this it. It saved me! All other suggestions didn't work for me either! Bizarre bug and sad that it still exists 2+ years later! VScode devs are becoming complacent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding *`"npm.enableScriptExplorer": true`* in the configuration file, you must display it because by default it is hidden!
You can unhide it by using the Views menu in the explorer:

[way to resolve issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8cIo.gif)

ref : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104591#issuecomment-673959672

Comment: left navigation bar : EXPLORER option -> check NPM SCRIPTS XD

Comment: This didn't work for me. Adding it to the settings file doesn't work and displays a warning which is not true. Something about it being in the views menu, but it isn't. It's completely gone!