# How can I disable actual commands in NPM scripts explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After latest update, my NPM explorer panel looks very wide now:

[image]

How can I disable this? I want to show only actual command name, like **dev**, **build**, **start**, etc...

I want it to look like before:

[image]

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943852/npm-scripts-not-shown-in-explorer-sidebar-how-to-shwo-them-again

Comment: it's not related

Comment: why not.......?

Comment: My issue is not about this panel is not showing up, it's about command description, you can see that in a screenshots.

Comment: why always display stuff that is visible in the tooltip, they usually give you the option to opt out, so I suggest you create an issue, you have 1 vote already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can - it was just added in [Improve appearance of NPM scripts tree](http://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123091).

I see nothing in the commit that mentions a setting to disable.  I think it may technically be a `task.detail` but the one setting that operates on that does nothing about the `NPM Scripts` view.

You may have to file an issue to get an option added.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - I think it was an easy change so it happened - but apparently there were no complaints while it was in the Insiders Build for three weeks.

Comment: Probably because not so many devs are actually using it.